# PowerShell error: the string is missing the terminator

Tags: powershell

For my script, I am getting an error I am not sure where it is coming from.

```
At C:\Users\RSpotton\Desktop\Script.ps1:30 char:189
+ ... ion)','$($_.OpenedEmail)','$($_.ClickedLink)','$($_.ReportedPhish)')"
+                                                                         ~ The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

```
$database = 'database'
$server = 'server'
$table = 'dbo.'+$_title

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "create table $table"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "update $table set Title=$_title"

Import-CSV $filename | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
    -Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
    -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Email)','$($_.LasTEmailStatusTimeStamp)','$($_.Department)','$($_.Location)','$($_.OpenedEmail)','$($_.ClickedLink)','$($_.ReportedPhish)')"
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with that line which is getting the error.

Comment: Your code and error message don't match as the code you posted doesn't have 30 lines. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code to make sure it exposes the error you're asking about, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code as well as the full error produced by that code. Do not paraphrase. Do not type from memory.

Comment: That is the isolated code of where the error is its just the error message that is from the whole script and it is the same exact thing with a different line number, not paraphrased and not from memory.

Comment: @RileySpotton - have you tried _removing_ the nasty, problematic backticks so that the `Import-CSV |` pipeline is all on one line? or perhaps using splatting to get the parameters into a neat package?

Comment: Yeah I have but it still gets the same error if its all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

What if you build the query string before the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet usi ng the `-f` string format operator.
That way you don't have to use backticks and IMO makes the code more readable.

Also, there was a typo in `$table = 'dbo.' + $_title` (missing dot after `$_`)

```
$database = 'database'
$server   = 'server'
$table    = 'dbo.' + $_.title

Import-CSV $filename | ForEach-Object {
    $qry = "insert into $table VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')" -f $_.Email, 
                                                                                      $_.LastEmailStatusTimeStamp, 
                                                                                      $_.Department, 
                                                                                      $_.Location, 
                                                                                      $_.OpenedEmail, 
                                                                                      $_.ClickedLink, 
                                                                                      $_.ReportedPhish
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query $qry
}
```